# Auto decimal for numbering in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, paragraph-styles, character-styles

Is there a way to make numbers separated with decimal symbol automatically and non-destructive in Indesign?
For example there is large numbers in my article which I'm designing now:

I have "six trillion" in number:
6000000000000
I want it to be something like this:
6,000,000,000,000
But automatically with decimal symbol for every 3 numbers, with somthin' like a Style.

- I can do it with GREP find and replace but it's a destructive method for sure.

Comment: I don’t think there’s a way to do that in InDesign, no.

Comment: In InDesign, styles generally can only change the appearance of text. They can't change or add characters. (With the exception of bulleted and numbered lists, which do indeed add characters.)